# Button disappearing, overflow needs to kick in at max-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, z-index

So basically, I have a tab bar where you have an add button to clone tabs and later edit them. My problem is that once so many tabs are added, my (left and right arrows) and my add button are removed. How can I add tabs, but keep my buttons from disappearing? Fixed position is not an option, I want the buttons next to the newest tab, and once the bar reaches a max-width, the buttons stay there. the arrows are to scroll through the tabs to see one's that will be hidden on overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/pHraC/1/

**html**

```
<div class="tabBox" style='max-width:800px'>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Certificate of Quantity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">COQ - Products/Chemicals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Movement Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Barge Survey</a></li>

    <ul class="tabButtons">
      <li><a href="#" class="tabNavLeft"><-</a></li>
      <li><a href="step-2b.html" class="tabNavRight">-></a></li>
      <li><div class="tabNavAdd" title="Add another report form to nomination" style="margin-top:6px">
      <input type='button' value='add' class='addTab' /></div></li>
    </ul>            
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
// add new tab
$("input.addTab").live("click", function (event) {
  var ultab = $(this).closest('.tabs'); // cache ul.tabs
  var li = ultab.children('li:not(.selected)').first(); // cache the row  
  ultab.children('li:last').after(li.clone().find('a').attr("href", "#").text('New Tab').end());
});
```

Comment: You can't nest a `<ul>` directly in another `<ul>`. You should wrap the submenu around with a `<li>` element - it is the only valid children for `<ul>`s. You will also have to escape the `>` and `<` signs - use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead.

You cannot float inline elements. Declare them as block instead.

Comment: Okay. Still doens't fix the overflow problem though. I'm using images for the arrows, but used text for the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you seperate the `.tabButtons` form the `.tabs`

```
<div class="tabBox" style='max-width:800px'>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Certificate of Quantity</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">COQ - Products/Chemicals</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Movement Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Barge Survey</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabButtons">
        <li><a href="#" class="tabNavLeft"> <- </a>
            </li>
        <li><a href="step-2b.html" class="tabNavRight">-></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tabNavAdd" title="Add another report form to nomination" style="margin-top:6px">
                <input type='button' value='add' class='addTab' />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

then, use `position:absolute` to put them where you like:

```
.tabBox { position:relative;
```

display: inline-block;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 50px 0 0;}
    .tabButtons {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:10px;
        z-index:2;
    }

You'll also have to define a position other than static to `.tabBox` for this to work and add some padding for the add button.

Finally, style the `.tabs li` like this:

```
.tabBox .tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 9px 0 0 0;
    padding: 3px 1px 0;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and add `white-space:nowrap;` and `display:inline-block;` to the `.tabBox .tabs`

here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/pHraC/4/

Comment: Absolute layout for the `add` button is an option, but according to the original question I assume the `add` button should be right next to the last tab, unless the tabs don't fit in one screen anymore (now it's always in the same place). That's what makes it harder.

Comment: Is it better now? Sure needs some position tunning, but I believe it is close to what you want...

Comment: The add button isn't cloning tabs, that's the issue in the matter.

Comment: Almost! Scrolling doesn't kick in for the new tabs. :/

Answer (score 0):

most simple way is to offset the top level `<ul>` with a padding and put the buttons as position absolute.

Here's a quick demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/ionko22/vURkK/

Oh and probably it's better to put your child `<ul>` within an `<li>`.

Comment: the add button isn't cloning anything. that's the issue is it is lost when adding.

Comment: I took out the js and extra fluff to demonstrate the html structure better.  If you want you can also check out jQuery's .on http://api.jquery.com/on/ which can make your "add another tab" function a lot simpler and easier to manipulate.